# Using vue-stripe-elements-plus with confirmCardSetup function

Tags: vue.js, stripe-payments

using vue-stripe-elements-plus for stripe payment
. https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-stripe-elements-plus.
But this library not support function "confirmCardSetup" of stripe. https://stripe.com/docs/js/setup_intents/confirm_card_setup. 
I want to kepp css for this component. have you can i retrive each value of stripe component.Thank you

Comment: Please reformulate, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The library appears to reference the old `handleCardSetup` method on Stripe.js which is an older name for the `confirmCardSetup` method: https://github.com/fromAtoB/vue-stripe-elements/blob/master/src/index.js#L26 & https://stripe.com/docs/js/deprecated/handle_card_setup. For now I think it's fine to use `handleCardSetup`, but I would recommend creating an issue on the vue-stripe-elements-plus Github page to let them know about the rename.

Comment: Thanks you @ttmarek. Now I'm using handleCardSetup but it wrong in some case. So i want to using confirmCardSetup instead

Comment: Dear @Oliver. Like ttmarek mention. I want to using confirmCardSetup instead for handleCardSetup for *vue-stripe-elements-plus* library. I want to known any way to override handleCardSetup methods. Thank you

Comment: @hieule, `handleCardSetup` has been deprecated, but it should still work as a temporary workaround until the vue-stripe-elements-plus maintainers update their library. Could you clarify what you mean by "it wrong in some cases"?

Comment: @ttmarek my web run in test enviroment and client report some card expired but still payment. So I thinks **handleCardSetup** method not stability, and i want to replace it

Comment: @hieule, `confirmCardSetup` and `handleCardSetup` would behave the exact name, it was largely a cosmetic change. The errors you're running into are likely unrelated, I would recommend writing in to Stripe support on that.